# The Crouton library is deprecated

Tags: bug, android-app

> [image: Readme page of Crouton]

The developer of [Crouton](https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton) suggests switching to Snackbars from the Android Design Support Library. This would be a good time to update the app and the dependencies with it. For those who weren't aware, this library is a dependency of the Stack Overflow Android App.

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: ZTE
- Device Model: ZTE A2017U
- OS Version: 7.0 (20170128.052618)

Comment: The apps are not developed any more, so I won't expect a fix.